# zend imap not copying mail to different folder

Tags: email, zend-framework, zend-framework2, copy, imap

When I try to copy an email to a different folder nothing happens. When I try to move the email it gets deleted but not moved, so the email does get found. I don't get any error messages either.

**Relevant Code:**

```
$unique_id = $mail->getUniqueId($messageNum);

var_dump($mail->copyMessage($mail->getNumberByUniqueId($unique_id), 'backup'));
```

The `var_dump` returns `NULL`.

Comment: try to output the list of folders, for sure backup exist, but it may be prefixed with something else or wrapped with some symbols. so $mail->getFolders() as $localName => $folder. if it does not work let me know I think I may have at home a working example.

Comment: This was the case, thanks! The folder was a subfolder so I needed `inbox/backup`

Comment: @peterpeterson Could you add your comment as an answer? You'll get the credit & points you deserve =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to output the list of folders, to make sure backup folder exists.

I may be prefixed with something else or wrapped with some symbols. so something like:

```
foreach ( $mail->getFolders() as $localName => $folder)
```